# Time Machine - Preparing takes forever... (> 6hours)

Tags: backup, time-machine

My time machine backup always takes a really long time. I actually don't know what caused the problem... but it's happening since a long time.

It takes about 6hours or longer, it doesn't matter if there are just small changes on the files or bigger ones. It always takes that long. But the backup finishes after that time.

It would be great if you could help me.
Thanks

```
... ~ %  tmutil status    
Backup session status:
{
    BackupPhase = Starting;
    ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
    DateOfStateChange = "2020-05-23 17:06:00 +0000";
    DestinationID = "013AD7A7-C1AE-4E9B-A28B-2F8539045349";
    Percent = "-1";
    Running = 1;
    Stopping = 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what mac do you have and what version of the system software.  Do you have an SSD? 6 hours is way too long. It takes less than an hour on my machine - a 2010 iMac running High Sierra.

Comment: I updated my first post. I'm using a 512 GB SSD.
And I backup onto a local Synology NAS via 100MBit

Answer (score 1):

How long since the previous backup?

There is a correlation between how much time/how many changes/the size of the changed files and how long it takes to prepare and how long it takes to complete.

Comment: Three days. Actually I don't think there is a correlation in my situation. I have not changed almost anything since the last backup...

Comment: I've never gone three days.  But when I go two weeks, a backup takes the better part of a day.  Just being logged in and online makes some changes, including "mobile backups."  But if the machine was shut off, I would not expect it to have that effect.

Comment: Yeah. It's the same if I create a backup 10minutes after the first one

Answer (score 0):

Time Machine backups run at low priority to ensure regular tasks go smoothly. This command should remove throttle on low priority tasks and speed up preparation, at the expense of some CPU and disk usage: `sudo sysctl debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled=0`

Restore default setting: `sudo sysctl debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled=1`

Comment: Used this and it's not changing anything.

Comment: I have seen zero evidence this made much difference or does anything than write a key that’s no longer considered for about 18 months. Is this something you know works and have measured this directly?

Comment: Actually I don't see any difference with this command.
If anyone could help me out this would be awesome.